# Debug TypeScript .ts files inside SharePoint

Tags: typescript

I am using a TypeScript project and then moving all the generated files into SharePoint. Is there something I need to do, like modify the .js files and .js.map files to make it so Visual Studio can attach to iexplore.exe and debug the .ts files?

Comment: I may have answered my own question. As long as the .js.map file is in a location that visual studio can get to easily, the any .js file running inside of IE should be debuggable through typescript breakpoints. In my case, Fiddler revealed that VS2013 was getting 401s to the .js.map file located inside SharePoint, so I changed the .js files to specify sourcemap files located locally on my laptop. It works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have another answer that is a bit simpler. Just use the OOTB TypeScript project and reference the JS files inside of SharePoint.